# .blade extension in laravel 5 is not working?

Tags: php, routes, laravel-blade, file-extension, laravel-5

### Laravel 5 - Blade Extension Error

---

I started using laravel 5 recently and its new. I'm using linux ubuntu 14.10.

---

Here is my code in the file app/Http/routes.php

- `Route::get('/test',function(){return view('test');});`

And I have created the test view here `resources/views/test.blade.php`

The error is when I use the `.blade.php` extension for test file as above the browser window is empty even I don't get any error message.

But when I renamed the file back to `test.php` without `.blade` it works fine !

I don't get what is happening. And when I used the default files like `welcome.blade.php` they work fine too.

---

I'm really confused. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I think  It is something wrong with my system. I tried  it on windows and now it works fine !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If default file `welcome.blade.php` works with `.blade.php` extension so it looks like there is something in your `test` file content that blocks rendering using Blade engine. Try to put this content into `welcome.blade.php` and check if it renders properly. If no, then look through your code and find what causes error.

Comment: thank ! I tried that too ! It does not work !. I think its something wrong with my system. Now I tried it on windows and I works fine !

Comment: Check file permissions and  owner/group settings.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I changed permissions for group and users and now its working fine ! Thank you . :-)

Answer (score 1):

I was having same issue. After changing permission everything now works fine

Comment: When using images you'll have to do this too. `sudo chgrp -R www-data yourProjectFolderName'